# On sufficient conditions on an analytic map to be algebraic(=regular)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-manifolds, complex-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth quasi-projective varieties defined over $\mathbf{C}$ and let
$$
f:X(\mathbf{C})\rightarrow Y(\mathbf{C})
$$
be a holomorphic map (not necessarily regular=algebraic). Then it is natural to ask what are additional conditions that one can impose on the data $(f,X,Y)$ in order to force
$f$ to be algebraic. Let me give 3 examples of such conditions:

1) Assume that $f$ is finite, unramified and that $X(\mathbf{C})$ has only one algebraic structure. Then a combination of Grauert-Remmert and GAGA implies that $f$ is algebraic. Note that (a postiori) the finiteness assumption on $f$ is essential since one has for example the exponential map $exp:\mathbf{C}\rightarrow\mathbf{C}^{\times}$ which is not algebraic but satisfy all the other assumptions (except the finiteness). 
Moreover, in general, it is also essential to assume that $X(\mathbf{C})$ has only one algebraic structure since there are examples of complex manifolds with at least 2 non-equivalent algebraic structures.

2) If $X$ is compact then from GAGA we ge automatically that $f$ is algebraic

3) Say that $X$ is a curve and $Y=\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbf{C})-\{0,1,\infty\}$. Then Picard's theorem (+removable singularity result) imply that $f$ is meromorphic on the compactification of $X$ and therefore $f$ is algebraic. (If I remember correctly, I think that there is some kind of generalization of Picard's result to higher dimension from the work of Kwack).

So with these 3 examples in mind, here is my question:

**Q**: what is known in the litterature about additional conditions that one may impose on the data $(f,X,Y)$ in order to force $f$ to be algebraic?

Comment: 1) is not quite correct since there are non-isomorphic algebraic varieties which are isomorphic as complex manifolds.

Comment: @Ulrich, Could you give me such an example?


Comment: So what is wrong in the following sketch: By Grauert-Remmert one may extend f to a holomorphic function $\bar{f}:\bar{X}\rightarrow \bar{Y}$ where the bars denote compactifications. Now look at the analytic coherent (algebra)-sheaf $\bar{f}_*O_{\bar{X}}^{an}$. By GAGA it comes from an (unique) algebraic (algebra)-coherent sheaf on $\bar{Y}$. Therefore $X$ and $f$ are algebraic. Isn't? 

Comment: On the example of a complex manifold carrying two different algebraic structures, take an affine curve $C$ of high genus and an algebraically non trivial line bundle $L$ on it. As $C$ is a Stein space, every line bundle on it is analytically trivial. But if $L$ and $C\times\mathbb{C}$ are algebraically isomorphic as varieties, then they are isomorphic as algebraic line bundles and that's impossible.

Comment: Hi @Samuele, so your example seems to work. So there must be something wrong in my reasoning...

Comment: So @Samuele, how do you prove your last statement: "But if $L$ and $C\times\mathbf{C}$ are algebraically isomorphic as varieties, then they are isomorphic as algebraic line bundles".

Comment: More examples of non-isomormphic algebraic varieties which are analytically isomorphic are given here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68421/simplest-examples-of-nonisomorphic-complex-algebraic-varieties-with-isomorphic-an


Comment: @Hugo: There will always be an algebraic structure on $X$ which will make $f$ algebraic (as you say, by Grauert-Remmert and GAGA) but there could be algebraic structures on $X$ which are not the restriction of the algebraic structure from $\bar{X}$ (if $\bar{X}$ is fixed).

Comment: I see, so missed this subtle point, thanks @ulrich for the explanation

Comment: so I just reedited my question. 

Comment: @Hugo: map a fiber of $L$ into $C\times\mathbb{C}$ through the alg.var.isomorphism, then project down to $C$; it must be constant (genus is high), so any isomorphism between the two bundles sends fiber to fiber (possibly on a different point). Now you can produce a bundle isomorphism by composing with the appropriate automorphism of the basis and adding on each fiber the right vector to fix the origin.

Comment: @Samuele, just to make sure I understand your argument, are you using implicitly the fact that the group of analytic automorphisms of $\mathbf{C}$ is equal to $z\mapsto az+b$ for $a\neq 0$ so that you know that over a small open set of the base you can normalize in a "coherent way" so that the tangent vector $0$ maps to $0$?  

Answer (score 4):

Borel (1972, J. Diffl. Geometry) proved that $f$ is always algebraic if $Y$ is the quotient of a bounded symmetric domain by a torsion-free arithmetic subgroup. This is a super-generalization of your example 3 (the quotient of the complex upper half plane by $\Gamma(2)$ is isomorphic to the projective line minus three points). The proof uses a generalization of work of Kwack plus the resolution of singularities.

Added: Kwack (1969) generalized the big Picard theorem by proving that any
holomorphic map from the punctured unit disk into a hyperbolic complex space
can be extended holomorphically to the whole unit disk. [A reduced complex
space is said to be hyperbolic if the Kobayashi pseudodistance is a distance
(Kobayashi 1967).]

Borel 1972 replaced the punctured disk in Kwack's theorem with a product of
punctured disks and disks.

Resolution of singularities allows you to realize a
smooth algebraic variety as an open subvariety of a smooth projective variety
in such a way that the boundary is a divisor with normal crossings (hence
analytically a product of punctured disks and disks).

These statements sometimes allow you to extend your map to an analytic map of projective varieties, where you can apply Chow's theorem to prove that it is regular.

References:

Borel, Armand. Some metric properties of arithmetic quotients of symmetric
spaces and an extension theorem.  J. Differential Geometry 6 (1972), 543--560.

Kwack, Myung H., Generalization of the big Picard theorem. Ann. of Math. (2)
90 1969 9--22.

Kobayashi, Shoshichi, Invariant distances on complex manifolds and holomorphic
mappings. J. Math. Soc. Japan 19 1967 460--480.

Comment: Thanks Anon. Can you give me a precise state? What is the analogue $\mathbb{P}^1-\\{0,1,\infty\}}$ in higher dimension?